# Storyboard sharing for two targets

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xib

I have an XCode project and I share UI between two targets. So I have common storyboard file for them. Target 2 does not need ViewController2 & ViewController3 so I delete those files from Target 2. But how do I fix the storyboard as it has references to ViewController2 & ViewController3 in Target 2?

Comment: why do you not move ViewController2 & ViewController3 in another storyboard which will be the part of target 1.

Comment: I already have everything in one storyboard. How do I now segregate carefully? And how do I link controller in one storyboard to another?